# C++ arbitrary length integers

Tags: c++, int, bit

In C++, is it possible to define arbitrary length integers?

So instead of having to use `uint64_t` for anything in between 33 and 64 bit, I could define my own 34 bit, 36 bit, etc., integers.

Comment: +1. Interesting. Waiting for answer.

Comment: If you are in the range of the machine architecture defined integers you can use [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to restrict numbers to a particular number of bits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle arbitrarily large integers](//stackoverflow.com/q/310276/)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has its own types like you did mention. long (32 bit on most platforms) and long long (64 bit on most platforms). If you need support for larger integers, you could use different libraries which limit the size of the integer to the size of your memory.

Libraries:

- GMPxx https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface
- Boost Multi Precision Library www.boost.org

Comment: Purely out of interest; does Boost Multiprecision support non power-of-two integer sizes?

Comment: @slugonamission - Computers are binary. How can they sdo anything different?

Comment: @EdHeal - by tricks in the wrapper. Create the storage as the next largest power-of-two, then perform arithmetic and truncate back down the the actual required bit width.

Answer (score 1):

As you are living in C++ world use https://gmplib.org/

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

For computation it would give you no advantage because today processors are optimized for either 32-bit or 64-bit arithmetic.

If you need them for size problems instead it could make sense to define your own container of n-bit numbers and this could be easily coded.

Even more general could be a container for mod-n numbers (i.e. for numbers from 0 to n-1, not necessarily for modulo with an exact power of two). For this an easy solution (but not space optimal) could be based on the largest power of n that fits in a 64-bit integer (e.g. you can pack 22 numbers between 0 and 6 into a single number between 0 and 2**64-1).

Comment: Your username is dating you - was it 6502A or 6502B? Any shadow RAM? BBC or Acorn Electon?

Comment: @EdHeal: Apple ][ :-)

Comment: I did not know that Apple had a 6502 procesor